# Is scope.$apply synchronous in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is the following code synchronous in AngularJS?

```
scope.$apply(function(){
  console.log('foo');
});
```

Comment: from [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) yes, there is [asyncApply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$applyAsync) for async

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is.

> $apply() is synchronous, and the browser blocks user input while
>   JavaScript is running on the main thread. Should the user perform
>   multiple input events quickly, the spec guarantees the browser will
>   queue those events.

More here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3782

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [`$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) is Synchronous.

IF you want Asynchronous counterpart, you can use

**`$applyAsync()`**

> Schedule the invocation of $apply to occur at a later time. The actual time difference varies across browsers, but is typically around ~10 milliseconds.
>
> This can be used to queue up multiple expressions which need to be evaluated in the same digest.

Also, read [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3782) thread.

Answer (score 1):

`$apply` calls `$eval`.

And `$eval` is synchronous.

So, yes, `$apply` is.

For asnychronous, there is `$evalAsync` method.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems to exist a `$scope.$applyAsync()` function, I would say that yes, this is a synchronous function.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is :

The angular source code is the following :

```
  $apply: function(expr) {
    try {
      beginPhase('$apply');
      try {
        return this.$eval(expr);
      } finally {
        clearPhase();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      $exceptionHandler(e);
    } finally {
      try {
        $rootScope.$digest();
      } catch (e) {
        $exceptionHandler(e);
        throw e;
      }
    }
```

and the function `beginPhase` :

```
function beginPhase(phase) {
  if ($rootScope.$$phase) {
    throw $rootScopeMinErr('inprog', '{0} already in progress', $rootScope.$$phase);
  }

  $rootScope.$$phase = phase;
}
```

Pay attention that it can throw an exception if there was currently a `$apply` or `$digest` in progress.

The `applyAsync` just pushes expressions into an array, that will be executed in the next $digest cycle.

If your aim is just to make sure there is no `$digest` in progress, you should do the following :

```
$timeout(
    scope.$apply(function(){
        console.log('foo');
    });
);
```

Which will be executed after the $digest cycle